# No communication App -> Watch App and App Installation fails on Apple Watch - iOS 9 Beta 5

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch, ios9

**Issue 1:**
Currently all apps I am trying to install on my Apple Watch via the Apple Watch iOS App fail without telling anything.

I tap on the "Show app on Apple Watch" slider, the app is starting to get installed, but coming the last 25% of the process, the App icon on the Watch just pops away and the slider in the iOS app goes back to uninstalled state.

This is not only happening for my own iOS + Watch App but with different other App examples as well. The last I tried was PotLoc from Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/samplecode/PotLoc/Introduction/Intro.html

**Issue 2:**
Also all Apps I deployed to the Watch and the iPhone (via Xcode, since this works as opposed to install via Apple Watch iOS app), are not able to talk in the direction iOS -> Watch OS via WCSession sendMessage.

I always receive the Log message:

`2015-08-21 15:58:05.728 Watch Smart[282:21056] Error: Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7006 "App ist nicht auf der Uhr installiert."`

`WCSession.defaultSession.isWatchAppInstalled()`

is always "NO".

The other direction works fine, though.

The hardware I am using is

- Apple iPhone 5s with iOS 9.0 (build 13A4325c)
- 42mm Sports Apple Watch version 2.0 (build 13S5325C)

Both devices say "current" on tried Software Update.

I think these two issues might be correlated.
Could it be a provisioning or another kind of rights issue?

**Another interesting fact:**
Two days ago there was a post on the Apple Developer Forums pointing to the exact same issue, but now it seems to have been deleted:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14649

The title was "WCSession sendMessage always fails on beta 5 Si... | Apple ..."

Comment: It now works for me, but I am not quite sure, what did the trick because I just did two things:
 
1. Reset and Re-coupled the Apple Watch and added a Passcode to it (what I never did before).
2. Downloaded Xcode 7 Beta 6 (but I am not sure if I recompiled anything before it started working).

Comment: I'm experiencing the same.. Did you restore the watch from a backup?

Comment: It didn't work for me. I tried with and without backup.

Comment: Ok, got it. I missed out there is a new XCode version. That was the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing XCode 7 Beta 6 fixes that problem.

Comment: Yes, I did. But that wasn't the problem.